# Using INDEX within a COUNTIF

Tags: excel

I'm trying to combine a couple of working formulae in Excel into a single formula to do a `lookup` and `countif`.

Currently I use :

```
=IF(I$7<>"",IF(INDEX('OtherWorkSheet'!$H:$H,I$8)="Yes","Y","N"),"")
```

to lookup if a value in a particular column (`H`) in a different work sheet is set to 'Yes' for a particular row selected using `INDEX` and a value in the `I$8` in the example above.

I am also using:

```
=COUNTIF('OtherWorkSheet'!$G17:$H17,"Yes")+COUNTIF('OtherWorkSheet'!$J17:$L17,"Yes")
```

to count up the number of columns that are set to 'Yes'.

I'm trying to combine the two so that I am counting the number of columns set to `Yes` for a given value of `I$8`.

(Please don't ask why! This is part of a much bigger complex spreadsheet and this is the one thing I can't get working. A full redesign of the rest of the spreadsheet is not an option, unfortunately)

The formula I have come up with is:

```
=IF(countif(INDEX('OtherWorkSheet'!$G:$H,I$8),"Yes")+countif(INDEX('OtherWorkSheet'!$J:$L,I$8),"Yes") > 1, "Y", "N" )
```

But this gives me reference errors as `countif` doesn't seem to like the result of `index` in its array argument.

If I use:

```
=IF(countif(INDEX('OtherWorkSheet'!$G:$G,I$8),"Yes")+INDEX('OtherWorkSheet'!$H:$H,I$8),"Yes")+INDEX('OtherWorkSheet'!$J:$J,I$8),"Yes")+INDEX('OtherWorkSheet'!$K:$K,I$8),"Yes")+countif(INDEX('OtherWorkSheet'!$L:$L,I$8),"Yes")) > 1, "Y", "N" )
```

then everything works, but this seems a bit cumbersome...

Can the formula be simplified and stillwork? (And still be copy and pasteable?)

Comment: The "working" formula appears to have been copied incorrectly.  The closing parenthesis after the third "YES" has no match.

Comment: Please share the excel/screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't fully tested this, but I'm pretty sure you just need the third argument to INDEX putting in as zero to keep it happy when indexing into a 2d range so that it knows to give you the whole row within the range

```
=IF(countif(INDEX('OtherWorkSheet'!$G:$H,I$8,0),"Yes")+countif(INDEX('OtherWorkSheet'!$J:$L,I$8,0),"Yes") > 1, "Y", "N" )
```